# How can I make this code easier/quicker/proper

Tags: vb.net

This has to be the most horrible thing I have ever created, there has to be a better way to go about doing this...
(Sub calls value from Numeric up and down limited to 25 - depending on value it must perform a button click)

```
Private Sub Activate_Drivers()
    Select Case nud_No_Participants.Value
        Case 1
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 2
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 3
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 4
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 5
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 6
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 7
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 8
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 9
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 10
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 11
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 12
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 13
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI13.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 14
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI13.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI14.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 15
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI13.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI14.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI15.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 16
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI13.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI14.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI15.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI16.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 17
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI13.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI14.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI15.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI16.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI17.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 18
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI13.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI14.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI15.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI16.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI17.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI18.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 19
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI13.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI14.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI15.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI16.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI17.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI18.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI19.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 20
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI13.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI14.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI15.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI16.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI17.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI18.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI19.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI20.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 21
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI13.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI14.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI15.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI16.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI17.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI18.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI19.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI20.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI21.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 22
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI13.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI14.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI15.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI16.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI17.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI18.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI19.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI20.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI21.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI22.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 23
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI13.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI14.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI15.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI16.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI17.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI18.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI19.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI20.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI21.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI22.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI23.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 24
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI13.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI14.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI15.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI16.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI17.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI18.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI19.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI20.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI21.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI22.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI23.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI24.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
        Case 25
            Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI4.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI5.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI6.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI7.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI8.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI9.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI10.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI11.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI12.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI13.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI14.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI15.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI16.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI17.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI18.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI19.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI20.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI21.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI22.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI23.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI24.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
            Form1.LapTimerGUI25.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: No, I can't see where you are going with this.

Comment: Ok so basically if the value of `nud_No_Participants` is 1, I need button of driver one to be clicked (`Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()`). If value is 2, I need button of driver one and driver two to be clicked. You see it accumulates up until 25 so the code will be very repetitive if I continue the way I am now. @Steve @LarsTech

Comment: Can you show the contents of the button click handlers?  It is very bad practice to programmatically "click" a button to get something done.  Show us what you are doing in those click handlers and then we can help.

Comment: I edited the question with the complete code.
The button click makes controls of a user control visible. And I have 25 user controls on my form. Therefore for each participant I want a user control to be visible @J...

Comment: I think you need to re-think your approach. What does the button click do? If your data model is an array of drivers, you could compress this down into a `for` loop. Perhaps if you prefix the question with your overall goal we might be able to offer more constructive options :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would put the Activate_Drivers function inside your Form1 and add a parameters for the nud_No_participants. I don't think you need all of your LapTimerGUI public.

Then I would put the timers inside a list

```
Dim lapTimers As New List(Of whatever)

lapTimers.Add(LapTimerGUI1)
lapTimers.Add(LapTimerGUI2)
lapTimers.Add(LapTimerGUI3)
lapTimers.Add(...)
```

To easely just loop through the list to Perform the click.

```
For index As Integer = 0 To nud_No_Participants.Value-1
    lapTimers(index).btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
Next
```

I have to say.. what you're doing looks strange. Maybe you have to rethink how you do it.

Comment: Damn yea I can see how my code looks strange when I see the correct way to go about my problem. Thanks @the_lotus

Comment: This is slightly less clumsy, but it's not a fantastic solution.  Guaranteed there is a more elegant way to refactor whatever code is inside the click handlers to avoid having to manually build a giant list.  It's still way too much ad-hoc repetition.

Comment: The problem I'm getting here with this solution is that `LapTimerGUI1` is a UserControl so I can't use an integer or string or whatever in `Dim lapTimers As New List (of ______)`
I think I might just leave this feature of the program out O_o

Comment: @AmatureCoder lists are generic - they can be of anything.  `Dim lapTimers As New List(Of UserControl)` or `...As New List(Of LapTimerGUI)`, or whatever you called your user control type.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @J... Ahhh that worked :D Thank you very much :)

And Thank you everyone else for all the help :D

Answer (score 2):

You can just swap it for a couple of if statements, so you progressively apply additional steps as the numbers increment.

I'm no VB coder, so here's a pseudo-code example:

```
Form1.LapTimerGUI1.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
If nud_No_Participants.Value > 1 Then
    Form1.LapTimerGUI2.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
End If
If nud_No_Participants.Value > 2 Then
    Form1.LapTimerGUI3.btn_Add_Remove_Driver.PerformClick()
End If
```

Comment: Need a `Then` in there.

Comment: And to follow up, for the love of all things good, refactor the business end of the code out of the click handler and just call a proper method.

Comment: Yeah I don't know VB, so it's just pseudo-code (updated ,thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @J... I assume this is a programming assignment so didn't mention that, but yes, definitely keep business logic, application flow, models and click handling separate if this is for some production application :)

Comment: Thank you, but this is what I'm doing but instead of If statement I'm using select case. In the end, they both going to be very painfull

Comment: In programming less is more. The above example doesn't have any duplicated code, which is what you should be aiming for. I don't think this answer is "painful", but the code in the question is something which should never be used.

Comment: @spikeheap ok, so what OP has not told us is that the pattern is not what he has shown but rather continues;  for 25 drivers, 25 buttons will need "clicking".

Comment: Yes I understand this probably isn't the correct method to be used, but with my limited knowledge of programming I could only think of this method :) Hence me asking you guys